# ES module path alias in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, es6-modules

I would like to use ES modules in **browser** environment in a convenient way like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Component from '../componens/Component';
```

I would like `react` to be resolved as `../vendors/react.js`, `react-dom` as `../vendors/react-dom.js` or `https://some.cdn/react-dom.min.js`. How do I do this without bundlers, just with native browser methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Importmaps* are now natively supported in all major browsers. See: https://caniuse.com/import-maps

Define like this:

```
<script type="importmap">
{
  "imports": {
    "mymodulejs": "https://my.cdn.path/mymodulejs@1.10.7",
  }
}
</script>
```

Use like this:

```
<script type="module">
  import myfunction from 'mymodulejs';

  console.log(myfunction());
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, this is unbelievable! https://jsfiddle.net/awdgk21t/

Comment: ;) ...................

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [import maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#importing_modules_using_import_maps) (original proposal [here](https://wicg.github.io/import-maps/)). You specify the map with a `script` with `type="importmap"` that listed the aliases, like this:

```
{
  "imports": {
    "react": "../vendors.react.js",
    "react-dom": "https://some.cdn/react-dom.min.js"
  }
}
```

Note that relative paths such as the one in your first example are relative to the document in which this `script` appears, not the module where you use the alias.

Import maps are supported by [all major modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/import-maps) and [Deno](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/basics/import_maps#import-maps).